# Склонение глаголов к числу

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать и говорить "продан 51 автомобиль" или "проданы 51 автомобиль"; "выдворены 31 гражданин" или "выдворен 31 гражданин" и на какое правило необходимо сослаться. Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

В этих случаях глагол согласуется с последним словом составного числительного, т.е. "продан 51 автомобиль, "выдворен 31 гражданин". Эти правила есть у РОзенталя

Answer (score 1):

Продан 51 автомобиль, выдворен 31 гражданин. Слово ОДИН всегда согласуется в роде, числе и падеже с существительным, к которому относится.
"Числительное один (одно, одна, одни) само по себе и в структуре составных лексем по падежу, а также по роду и числу всегда согласуется
с существительным, к которому относится: сто сорок один карандаш,
нет ста сорока одного карандаша, ста сорока одному карандашу, ста со-
рока одним карандашом, о ста сорока одном карандаше" [Здесь](http://rudocs.exdat.com/docs2/index-596352.html?page=10).